# correct understanding mathematical question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

suppose that  we have following question,this question is not related to  itself mathematics confusion,but language problem and please help me to clarify  English language terms  in mathematics. question is this :

Simon arrived at work at $8:15$ A.M. and left work at $10:30$ P.M. If Simon gets paid by the hour at a rate of $10$ dollar  and time and ½ for any hours worked over $8$ in a day. How much did Simon get paid?

from the beginning i could not understand  what was  main trick in this question,but i have only one :what does mean time and $½$  clearly as i understand  during the  $8$ hour,he is paid  $10$ dollar  per hour,but after  $8$ ?clearly from $4:15$ till $10:30$,we have $6$ hour and $15$ minute,so what is meaning of time and $1/2$?please help me,because i am preparing for GRE exam,and i would like to clarify every English tricks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time and a half means that each hour after $8$ hours counts as if it was $1\frac{1}{2}$ "regular" hours. In other words, for overtime (time in excess of $8$ hours) he/she gets paid $15$ dollars an hour.

Comment: so $6$ hour means  $6*3/2$?after $6$ hour,because $15$ is multiplied by $6.25$

Comment: Yes, either think of it as the same pay as for $9$ hours at $10$ dollars an hour, or equivalently  $15$ dollars an hour for $6$ hours. The second way to view it is probably more useful, and less potentially confusing. But in the answer I was trying to explain the phrase "time and a half."

Comment: Nicolas thanks very much,i understood clearly  about $15$ dollar,but only one thing left,from  $4:15$  to $10:30$ is $6$ hour and $15$ minute,so $15$ minute is  $1/4$,so it should be  $15$ multiplied by $6+1/4$ right?

Comment: Yes, in a mathematical problem. In the real world the contract might say "for each hour or part thereof."

Comment: You are welcome. Words whose meaning one takes for granted can seem pretty obscure to someone not accustomed to them. In subtle ways, standardized exams are not quite as "fair" as their designers think.

Comment: yes,clearly GRE mathematics it is not difficult at all,just  average level,but english makes it more complex, and main problem is that. you can't complain  about this,they will say  you must be prepared for this